# If $g \circ f $ is injective, why must $f$ be injective but not $g$?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

I'm trying to prove that if $g \circ f$ is injective, then f must also be injective. I have written a proof, which I believe has a bad step in it, and I would like feedback.

Assume $g \circ f$ is injective. Now suppose $g\circ f(x) = g\circ f(y)$ for some $x, y$ in the domain of $f$ (call it $X$). Because the composition is injective, $x = y$.

Now suppose $f$ were not injective. Then for some $x', y' \in X, ~f(x') = f(y')$ but $x' \neq y'$. Thus $g \circ f(x') = g \circ f(y')$ but  $y' \ne x'$ This implies $g \circ f$ is not injective, which is a contradiction. Therefore $f$ must be injective. $\Box $

This seems spurious to me, because it implies that $g$ itself needs to be injective (I feel but cannot state rigorously that this is implicit in the step that derives the contradiction) and I know that $g$ need *not* be injective itself (though again, I know this heuristically and cannot think of an example).

Here is another question that is identical ([Composition of functions injective implies one of them is injective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1324627/composition-of-functions-injective-implies-one-of-them-is-injective)) but it seems like the same assumption is being made; which is that the fact that $~f(x') = f(y') \Rightarrow g \circ f(x') = g \circ f(y')$ and that this contradicts the injectivity of $g$ as $x' \ne y'$

Can anyone help clarify my thinking here?

Comment: No it does not imply $g$ is injective, because that would require the statement $g(x') = g(y')$. What you have is that $f(x')=f(y') = z$ and then $g(z)=g(z)$ is a tautology.

Comment: Because there are counterexamples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\{0\}$, $Y=\{1,2\}$ and $Z=\{3\}$. Define
\begin{align}
f\colon X&\to Y, & f(0)&=1,\\
g\colon Y&\to Z, & g(1)&=g(2)=3
\end{align}
Then $g\circ f$ is injective, but $g$ is not.

Thus there's no way to prove that $g\circ f$ injective implies $g$ injective.

---

Your proof is good, but has some redundant parts.

> Suppose $g\circ f$ is injective and that $f(x)=f(y)$; then $g\circ f(x)=g\circ f(y)$ and, by injectivity of $g\circ f$, we conclude $x=y$. Therefore $f$ is injective.

There's nothing more to prove.

But, as you see from the example, $g$ need not be injective: you just use the obvious fact that, if $a=b$, then $g(a)=g(b)$. In this case $a=f(x)$ and $b=f(y)$, which are equal by assumption.

Comment: Thanks. Any input regarding the rest of the question?

Comment: @BenL I added some comments

Answer (score 3):

Think of an injective function as one that *preserves difference*.  If $f$ collapses two points into each other, so that $f(a)=f(b)$, then there is no way for $g$ to unentangle them; $g\circ f$ must also collapse $a$ and $b$.

But $g\circ f$ can still be injective even if $g$ collapses points *as long as it doesn't collapse points in the range of $f$*.  For example, suppose that $g(u)=g(v)$, but there is no solution to $f(x)=u$.  Then the fact that $g$ fails to distinguish between $u$ and $v$ is not important for the function $g\circ f$, since the point $u$ is irrelevant.

For a concrete example, suppose that $f$ maps a set of children to the month of their birth, and $g$ maps each month to the number of days in the month.  Then $f$ will be injective as long as no two children have the same birth month.  $g$ is clearly not injective, as $g(\textrm{January})=g(\textrm{March})=31$.  But $g\circ f$ might be injective, depending on the set of children.  If there are only three children, Alice, Bob, and Cathy (born in January, February, and April respectively), then $g\circ f$ will be injective.

Formally, if $f:X\to $ and $g:Y\to Z$, then $g\circ f$ will be injective if and only if $f$ and $g\vert_{R(f)}$ are injective, where $R(f)\subseteq Y$ is the range of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

First you don't have to assume $g\circ f$ is injective because it is not stated that  $g\circ f$ is injective if and only if $f$ is. What is stated is ‘only if’.

Second, if $f$ is *not* injective: you prove that $g\circ f$ cannot possibly be injective. This is not a proof by `contradiction`, but a proof by `contrapositive` (the assertion $A\implies B$  is logically equivalent to the assertion $\neg B\implies \neg A$).

Comment: No; the statement of the theorem in my text (And in my professor's notes) is "Show that if $g \circ f $ is injective then so is $f$.  I'm also not clear how this *isn't* proof by contradiction. I suppose the opposite is true; then show that this assumption leads to a contradiction of my initial assumptions. That seems like proof by contradiction to me. Could you elaborate?

Comment: ‘No’ what? I explained you proved this in the second part by proving that if $f$ is not injective ($\neg B$), then $g\circ f$ is not ($\neg A$). In other words you proved $\neg B\implies\neg A$, which is equivalent to $A\implies B$).

Comment: "No" as in you misread or misunderstood the statement I was trying to prove. I was proving injectivty of $f$ as an implication of injectivty of $g \circ f$. That is different from an 'only if' statement, and it makes perfect sense in such a case to start out assuming the conditional statement is true.

Comment: But `only if` (̓$\Rightarrow$) means precisely that, as opposed to `if` ($\Leftarrow$).