# $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ two functions such that $f\circ g\circ f$ is bijective. Then so are $f, g$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

**Problem:** Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets and $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ two functions such that $f\circ g\circ f$ is a bijection. Prove that $f$ and $g$ are also bijection.

**Proof Attempt:** We first show that $f$ is an injection. Let $f(x)=f(y)$ then $$g(f(x))=g(f(y))$$
$$f(g(f(x)))=g(g(f(y)))$$
$$(f\circ g\circ f)(x)=(f\circ g\circ f)(y)$$
$$x=y.$$
So it is an injection.

Now we will show $f$ is a surjection. Let $y\in B$ then there exists an $x\in A$ such that $(f\circ g\circ f)(x)=y.$ Or in other words for any $y\in B$ there exists an element $x'=g(f(x))\in A$ such that $f(x')=y.$ Hence $f$ is a surjection. Thus $f$ is a bijection.

Now we will show that $g$ is a bijection. We know that $f$ is a bijection and hence $f^{-1}$ is a bijection so we have that $f^{-1}\circ f\circ g\circ f\circ f^{-1}$ is a bijection. But this mapping is identical to $g$ and so we have that $g$ is a bijection.

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: Well done.  I see no problems.

Comment: @Randall Thanks!

Comment: Finally made the 2k mark!

Comment: Note that this can be deduced from the result at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1324627/composition-of-functions-injective-implies-one-of-them-is-injective.

Comment: @Hello_World: Perhaps you should self-answer this so it doesn't hang around as an unanswered question.

Comment: A shorter proof would be as follows, since $ f \circ g \circ f = ( f \circ g) \circ f $ is bijective, it is in particular injective, by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1324627/composition-of-functions-injective-implies-one-of-them-is-injective ,  $f$ is then injective. And  $ f \circ g \circ f = f \circ ( g \circ f)$ is in particular surjective, by result stated above, $f$ is then surjective. Hence $f$ is then bijective. By your argument above, $g$ is then bijective.

Answer (score 1):

Just to avoid this question to stay unanswered: it is a valid proof.