# a question about bijectivity

Tags: functions

i have a question

let $E,F$ and $G$ three sets.

$f:E\rightarrow F$

$g:F\rightarrow G$

$h:G\rightarrow E$

prove that if : $f \circ h\circ g$ and $h \circ g\circ f$ are injectives and $g \circ f\circ h$ is surjective. then $f,g,h$ are bijectives.

i have proved that:

$g$ is injective and surjective.

and $g\circ f$ is injective and surjective.

how i can prove that $f$ and $ h$ are bijectives

please help me with this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f\circ h\circ g$ and $h\circ g\circ f$ are injective, $g$ and $f$ are injective. And, since $g\circ f\circ h$ is surjective, $g$ is surjective. Therefore, $g$ is a bijection.

But, since $g$ is a bijection and $f\circ h\circ g$ is injective, $f\circ h$ is injective. Therefore, $h$ is injective. And since $g$ is a bijection and $g\circ f\circ h$ is surjective, $f\circ h$ is surjective. Therefore, $f$ is surjective.

Since $f$ is injective and surjective, it is a bijection. And since $f$ is a bijection and $f\circ h$ is a bijection too, $h$ is a bijection.

Comment: thanks for the help.But i think that your proof is not rigorous.

Comment: Here are been used results that are quite known, regarding functions composition btw if @ananadilwa3r you need it you can fill the missing pieces helping you with this [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1324627/composition-of-functions-injective-implies-one-of-them-is-injective)

Comment: how do you proved that if $g$ is a bijection and $f\circ h\circ g$ is injective  then $f\circ h$ is injective

Comment: If $f\circ h$ is not injective, then there are distinct elements $y$ and $y'$ in $G$ such that $f(h(y))=f(h(y'))$. Since $g$ is surjective, there are elements $x$ and $x'$ in $F$ such that $g(x)=y$ and that $g(x')=y'$ and, since $y\neq y'$, $x\neq x'$. But then $f(h(g(x)))=f(h(g(x')))$. That's impossible, since $f\circ h\circ g$ is injective and $x\neq x'$.

Comment: thanks for the help

Comment: @ananadilwa3r the key facts being used here are: 1. Compositions of injective maps are injective, and similarly for compositions of surjective maps. 2. the first function in a surjective composition is surjective, 3. the last function in an injective composition is injective. 4. Bijective functions have inverses. All of these would be good exercises to prove.  In particular, you know $f\circ h = (f\circ h\circ g)\circ g^{-1}$ (from 4), and you know the right hand side is injective (from 1).